# jQuery toggle between 4 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a problem with jQuery toggle between 4 divs. I have no idea why it doesn't work. It just showed me the first div and didn't do anything. When I used it on another webpage, it worked.
Code is below:

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 75%; border: 0; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;" align="center" padding="10"><tr>
<td width="50%" align="center"><a class="ukaz" target="1"></a></td>
<td width="50%" align="center"><a class="ukaz" target="2"></a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="center"><a class="ukaz" target="3"></a></td>
<td width="50%" align="center"><a class="ukaz" target="4"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="div1" class="cil" style="display:block;">
text
</div>
<div id="div2" class="cil">
text
</div>
<div id="div3" class="cil">
text
</div>
<div id="div4" class="cil">
text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .cil {
 display: none;
 }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.ukaz').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.cil').eq(index).slideDown();
        jQuery('.cil').not(newTarget).slideUp();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current expression finds the `index` of the clicked element but it doesn't know the context to which element it needs to find `index` to. You need to find the `index` of the click element via using all elements matching class `.ukaz`

```
$('.ukaz').click(function () {
    var index = $('.ukaz').index($(this));
    $('.cil').slideUp();
   $('.cil').eq(index).slideDown();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/qgo90beb/1/

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Friday :)